# Запятые в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Он исчезнет, если Вы откажитесь от всех государственных субсидий, и субсидий муниципалитета, на которые соглашались.

Что не так с запятыми? Почему? Если можно, то сделать синтаксический разбор ещё. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он исчезнет, если Вы откажЕтесь от всех государственных субсидий и субсидий муниципалитета, на которые соглашались. Союз "и" соединяет два однородных дополнения  (...от субсидий и субсидий), поэтому запятая не нужна. В целом это предложение сложноподчиненное, с двумя придаточными предложениями (условным и определительным): Он исчезнет (при каком условии?),если Вы откажетесь от всех государственных субсидий и субсидий муниципалитета (каких?), на которые соглашались. Такая связь частей сложноподчиненного предложения называется последовательным подчинением

Answer (score 0):

Он исчезнет, если Вы откажЕтесь от всех государственных субсидий и субсидий муниципалитета, на которые соглашались.
 Союз И соединяет два однородных члена предложения, поэтому запятая здесь не ставится. Остальные знаки препинания проставлены верно.